# Metadata of Stored Procedure Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use Sql Server 2008.

I want to get the **column names** and **data types** of the result set of a stored proc. How can I do it? Something like INFORMATION_SCHEMA would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an application you can inspect the potential result set by first issuing SET FMTONLY ON. However this is being phased out in future version of SQL Server in favor of a much more robust metadata discovery mechanism. In the meantime, the best you're probably going to get is by using OPENQUERY against a loopback server. This assumes your stored procedure returns exactly one result set - if there are more than one, it isn't quite going to work.

For example:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server     = 'LOOPBACK_SERVER',
    @srvproduct = '',
    @provider   = 'SQLOLEDB',
    @datasrc    = @@SERVERNAME;

SELECT * INTO #foo 
    FROM OPENQUERY(LOOPBACK_SERVER, 'EXEC db_name.dbo.proc_name');

SELECT c.name, t.name, t.max_length, t.precision, t.scale
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
    ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo');

DROP TABLE #foo;
```

Note this also assumes that you aren't using any CLR UDTs or alias types.

Comment: +1 Visual Studio seems to be able to determine result sets when you add an SP to a DBML file.  I wonder if this is what it does under the hood

Comment: You could trace to be sure, but I suspect it either uses SET FMTONLY ON or it manually parses the text. What does Visual Studio show when the procedure has more than one result set?

Comment: Just traced, and it does use SET FMTONLY.  DBML only shows the first result set, you can retrieve more, but then you have to define the result set yourself.

Comment: +1 you can also condense this a bit using openrowset to avoid a link registration & exec('use tempdb exec sp_columns #foo')`